# py2app: modulegraph missing scan_code

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, py2app

For some reason I can't explain or google, py2app crashes on me even with the simplest examples. Im using a python 3.4.1 virtual environment created as `Projects/Test/virtenv` which has py2app installed via pip.

Here is the output of `$pip list`:

```
altgraph (0.12)
macholib (1.7)
modulegraph (0.12)
pip (1.5.6)
py2app (0.9)
setuptools (3.6)
```

foo.py is a hello world example file saved in Projects/Test/ and contains a single line:

```
print('hello world')
```

setup.py is saved in Projects/Test as generated by `$py2applet --make-setup foo.py`:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['foo.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Here is the full output of running `$python setup.py py2app` (all pip and python commands were done with the virtual enviroment activated) :

```
running py2app
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone/app
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone/app/temp
creating /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/dist
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/python3.4-standalone/app/Frameworks
*** using recipe: lxml ***
*** using recipe: ftplib ***
*** using recipe: sip ***
*** using recipe: ctypes ***
*** using recipe: xml ***
*** using recipe: pydoc ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 943, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 824, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/recipes/virtualenv.py", line 80, in check
    mf.scan_code(co, m)
AttributeError: 'ModuleGraph' object has no attribute 'scan_code'
```

Can someone please explain whats going on and how to fix it?

EDIT: [here](https://pythonhosted.org/modulegraph/modulegraph.html#modulegraph.modulegraph.scan_code) is the documentation for scan_code in modulegraph.py, however the file found in Projects/Test/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py contains a function called _scan_code with a leading underscore. Is this some type of change that broke py2app?

EDIT: posted [this](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/modulegraph/issue/22/scan_code-in-modulegraphpy-contains-a)

EDIT: Manually removing leading underscores from a couple function definitions in the file mentioned allowed py2app to run without error. I'm still confused regarding what happened

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and solved it now.

I referred to this [post](http://www.marinamele.com/from-a-python-script-to-a-portable-mac-application-with-py2app).

First, search for the path

```
$ /yourenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/recipes/virtualenv.py
```

Next, open this file `virtualenv.py`, look for `scan_code` or `load_module` and change it to `_scan_code` or `_load_module`.

Last, try to run your app

Comment: I found out this was a small bug in p2app. The developer is already aware of it.

Comment: Seems fixed in https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/commits/4d6629f430b9ddfbcd0c0bbb10c526d535bc2995

Comment: @Andrei the bug only appears to address the _scan_code issue in the code and not the load module.